# How to sort array of strings which contains both negative and positive numbers in c++.?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, algorithm, sorting

> ```
> String str[]={"-123","89","-10","456"};
> ```
>
> `str` is an array of strings, with each string in the format of an integer, and you have to perform sorting on this array in `O(n log n)` time.
>
> The strings in `str` can represent both positive and negative integers. The maximum length of these strings is 1024 characters.

I know one solution of this problem is to convert the strings into numbers, then compare them apart from this; is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: 1024 characters – i. e. digits – you'll need very large integers for...

Comment: @RSahu my mistake i have edited the question now

Comment: @Aconcaguan yes i have used boost multiprecision library of cpp for that

Comment: Another version of the idea in the answers doing string-based comparisons: you could partition the list into negative and non-negative parts, and then use two simpler comparison functions for each category to sort the parts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another solution is to implement your own comparison function:

- Check the first character of both strings. If one starts with a digit and the other starts with a `-`, then the string that starts with `-`
  is the smaller number.
- If both strings start with a digit, then compare the length of the
  strings. The shorter string is the smaller number. If both strings
  are the same length, perform a standard string compare.
- If both strings start with `-`, then compare the length of the
  strings. The longer string is the smaller number. If both strings are
  the same length, perform a standard string compare, but negate the
  result.

Comment: But we need to assume that there are no leading zeros, these would have to be ignored when considering string lengths. Negative zeros (`"-0"`), if they exist, would get sorted in front of the normal ones, but that seems fine to me...

Comment: That can be easily remedied. Use index from `find_first_not_of("0")` and pass those to `compare()` overload which asks for pos/len for both sides of comparison.

Comment: @Aconcagua You are correct that I hadn't considered leading zeros. Thanks to @ TanveerBadar for providing the solution to that. As for negative zeros, sorting them before positive zeros seems fine to me as well.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a minimal and potentially insufficient (doesn't handle leading zeroes, whitespace, etc.) example that does what you'd like.

The comments explain what it's doing. :)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> strings = {
      "-1", "-1", "-20", "-4", "3", "0", "-0", "1", "20", "20", "44020",
  };

  // Assumes everything in "strings" has no whitespace in it.
  // Assumes everything in "strings" does not have leading zeroes.
  // Assumes everything in "strings" is an ascii representaion of an integer.
  // Assumes everything in "strings" is nonempty.
  std::sort(strings.begin(), strings.end(),
            [](const std::string &a, const std::string &b) {
              const bool a_is_negative = a[0] == '-';
              const bool b_is_negative = b[0] == '-';
              if (a_is_negative != b_is_negative) {
                // If they have different signs, then whichever is negative is
                // smaller.
                return a_is_negative;
              } else if (a.length() != b.length()) {
                // If they have the same sign, then whichever has more
                // characters is larger in magnitude. When the sign is negative,
                // the longer (more digits) number is "more negative". When
                // positive, the longer (more digits) number is "more positive".
                return (a.length() < b.length()) != a_is_negative;
              } else {
                // Otherwise a lexicographic comparison of "a" and "b" will
                // determine which string is larger in magnitude. Using the same
                // logic above, we account for the "negative vs. positive"
                // comparison.
                return (a < b) != a_is_negative;
              }
            });

  for (const auto &str : strings) {
    std::cout << str << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ah seems the other answer outlines the same logic as I've written in my response. I'll leave this up though they were first. I used code to express my response, he used words. :)

Comment: Explicit conversion to bool is not necessary, if you provide (trailing) return type. I personally would consider that more readable. You could as well use `!=` instead of `^`, having same result for booleans, but result is boolean already, again making the explicit cast obsolete (and additionally the parentheses...).

Comment: Damn, you stole my (opportunity to) answer: [My demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef06cb5af6a1a183). ;-)

Comment: Nice @Aconcagua -- I was being lazy and writing my thoughts instead of thinking about writing clean code. I've adopted your suggestions as it doesn't materially change the answer.

Comment: Whereas lambda can be fine, I think that the lambda is large and that it makes sense to have dedicated function instead (`less_as_number`?).